# Angular Module has no exported member 'fromEvent'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I was trying to follow along with the official Angular tutorial on [practical observable usage](https://angular.io/guide/practical-observable-usage#type-ahead-suggestions) and attempted to import the "fromEvent":

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';
```

However, it keeps throwing an error message which states **"myApp/node_modules/rxjs/Rx" has no exported member 'fromEvent'**

I've already searched SO and Googled, with no luck.

Comment: First Google search shows [this](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/fromevent.html), where it's imported from a subfolder, does that work?  What version of rxjs?

Comment: Wow, that was fast! My Google-foo is not up to snuff: What was your search string? And yes, that helps tremendously!

Comment: [fromEvent rxjs](https://www.google.com/search?q=fromevent+rxjs&oq=fromevent+rxjs&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l2j0l2.1987j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), glad it helped!

Answer (score 9):

'fromEvent' appears to be part of Observable. You can import it like this:

```
import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs/observable/fromEvent';
```

Unlike answers elsewhere, importing "Observable" did not help, and I had to rely on VS code correctly auto suggesting where to import from (After spending quite a bit of time trying to figure out why the import did not work).

Comment: for now it seems that the correct way to import "fromEvent", would be
`import { fromEvent } from 'rxjs';`